# zlib in c#: decompress byte arrays > 32 Kb

Tags: c#, zlib

I have tried to decrompress byte arrays or streams above 32 kb with several zlib-implementations (dotnetzip, zlib.net, System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream), but I was not able to decompress byte arrays above 32 kb.

It seems as if System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream requires the zlib-header of a whole file, but I have only the byte array, not a whole file.

If I want to get the decompressed stream using `byte[] result = UncompressBuffer(input)` from dotnetzip, the result is always cut at 32 kb.

I tried to change the WorkingBufferSizeDefault, but it did not help.

I also tried alternatives, using a MemoryStream to write all deflated bytes into the stream, but this resulted in an infinite loop in several zlib wrappers.

Does anyone have an idea, where to change dotnetzip or which alternative to use for large byte arrays?

Comment: It's not really clear what your situation is - what do you mean by "I have only the byte array"? What byte array? Can you provide a [mcve] to clarify?

Comment: ok, we have byte[] input = new byte[40000]; for(int i=0; i<input.length;i++) input[i] = i % 2 == 1 ? 1 : 0; byte[] compressed = CompressBuffer(input); byte[] uncompressed = UncompressBuffer(compressed);

Comment: sorry, this version had some problems. I changed it and the result worked... so I have to check my input data, maybe there is a problem inside.

Comment: Please edit the question rather than putting code in comments. But it sounds like for the moment you should just delete the question.